# Empty set in LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, set

```
    public static string ToHtml(List<int> tags)
    {
        var found = Values.Where(v => tags.Contains(v.Key));

        if (found.Any())
            return found.Select(v => v.Value.ToHtml()).Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1 + v2) + " ";
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }
```

The code first finds a set of pairs from the dictionary where a condition is met. Then if the set has any elements, each pair is converted to html and result strings aggregated (something like String.Join("", ...)). However, if there are no found pairs, return String.Empty.

My question is: how to do it in a simple, clever and clear way, without writing so much?

I came up with this:

```
    public static string ToHtml(List<int> tags)
    {
        return Values
            .Select(v => tags.Contains(v.Key) ? v.Value.ToHtml() : null)
            .Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1 + v2);
    }
```

But unfortunately I can't now add " " (space) after the string in case the set is not empty. If the set is empty I want to return String.Empty, otherwise the string + " ".

Comment: You want `String.Join()`

Comment: String.Join("", ...) + " " - in case anything was found. And String.Empty in case nothing was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Simple and clear" is not always synonymous with "minimalistic". You shouldn't be trying to use `.Select()` for both projection and filtering. Filtering is what `.Where()` is for. So first select the items you need, and then act accordingly.

In newer versions of .NET (4.0+), you can just use `string.Join()`:

```
public static string ToHtml(List<int> tags)
{
    var found = Values.Where(v => tags.Contains(v.Key))
                      .Select(v => v.Value.ToHtml());

    return found.Any()
        ? string.Join("", found) + " "
        : string.Empty;
}
```

In older versions of .NET, you can do practically the same, but you need a `.ToArray()`:

```
public static string ToHtml(List<int> tags)
{
    var found = Values.Where(v => tags.Contains(v.Key))
                      .Select(v => v.Value.ToHtml());

    return found.Any()
        ? string.Join("", found.ToArray()) + " "
        : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Lovely. Looks beautiful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting the `ToHtml` method, you could aggregate with a space separator and then remove trailing spaces:

```
const char space = ' ';
var s = values
            .Select(v => tags.Contains(v.Key) ? v.Value : String.Empty)
            .Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1 + space + v2)
            .TrimEnd(space);
```

[rextester sample here](http://rextester.com/VEET86646), with a test for empty/not empty intersection.